# Permutation orders in specific symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, notation, permutation-cycles

I've recently delved into symmetric groups and stumbled upon a notation that's left me somewhat puzzled. When analyzing a particular symmetric group, let's call it $S_n$, I've come across the set notation: $\{\text{ord}(f)\ |\ f \in S_7\}$.

For context, in the case where $n=7$, would the notation "permutations of length 7" strictly refer to 7-cycle structures? Or does it encompass all potential permutations in $S_7$, such as the identity, 1-cycles, 2-cycles, and the like?

Comment: The notation here, $f\in S_7$, means all permutations in $S_7$. Why would it mean only *some* elements of $S_7$?

Comment: I will note that nothing in the notation says "permutation of length $7$". In general, [the length of a permutation $\rho$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $\rho$ can be written as a product of $k$ transpositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3473266/742), but that does not occur in the notation you have quoted.

Comment: Thanks, @arturomagidian for the answer.
The "permutations of length 7" are mentioned explicitly in the question. So, the question is to find the set of orders noted by the notation of permutations of length 7.

Comment: There is no "arturomagidian" here, as far as I am aware. Yes, *you* mention "permutation of length 7", but you preface that by putting forth notation, and the **notation** does not mention "permutations of length 7". If you were supposed to include "length" somewhere, you failed to do so in this post.

Comment: If by "length of a permutation" you mean what I stated above (least $k$ such that the permutation can be written as a product of $k$ transpositions) then note that $7$-cycles do *not* have "length 7", since they can be written as a product of $6$ transpositions. We *do* talk about "length of a cycle" (which is the same as its order), but for permutations that are not cycles the notion is not so clear, so you'd need to say what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is set theoretic in nature.

The notation, for a function $\varphi$ from a set $X$,

$$\{\varphi(x)\mid x\in X\}$$

means the set of values of $\varphi$ at *each* $x$ in $X$.

For example, for $\varphi(x)=2x$ and $X=\{1,2\}$, we get

$$\{\varphi(x)\mid x\in X\}=\{2,4\}.$$

Also ${\rm ord}: S_7\to \Bbb N$ is the *order* of each element of $S_7$.

Comment: Does that mean if the requirement is to provide the set of orders of all permutations of length 7 in $S_7$, that means to list the orders of all the elements in $S_7$?

Comment: For that, @ZenithZero, you need $$\{{\rm ord}(f)\mid f\in S_7, {\rm length}(f)=7\}.$$

Comment: In that case, can we say the following?
$$f = (123)(4)(5)(6)(7) \in \{ f \in S_7, length(f) = 7 \}$$

Comment: No, @ZenithZero: the length of $x=(123)(4)(5)(6)(7)$ is three, since $x=(123)$. Furthermore, there is a lot wrong with $$f = (123)(4)(5)(6)(7) \in \{ f \in S_7, length(f) = 7 \}.
$$ First, you used $f$ inside and outside the set. Second, you mean $$\{f\in S_7\mid {\rm length}(f)=7\}$$ as the set, since, otherwise, it would be the set containing the expression $f\in S_7$ and the expression $length(f)=7$. Use `${\rm text}(x)$` for ${\rm text}(x)$ and `$x\mid y$` for $x\mid y$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now!
So, the right notation is:
$$ x = (a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6 a_7) \in \{ f \in S_7 \mid length(f) = 7 \} $$
E.g., $x = (1234567)$